# Republic of Ireland .csv to mark out points on site. Which map/co-ordinate system to use?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, csv

I need to be able to create points in Arcmap 10.1 (or 10.4) in a geo-referenced map layer which I can then export as a .csv file and then use in my gps (GeoExplorer 6000) to mark out those points on site.

I have a process that works for this in England/Wales/Scotland but I am not sure how to do this in the Republic of Ireland or Northern Ireland as I don't know which co-ordinate system to use or even which maps to download/buy.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I usualy search for proper coordinate systems in the web "epsg.io". You can search "Ireland" in that web and you obtain several results. Maybe "IRENET95 / UTM zone 29N" match your needs but I'm not sure because I've never worked with Irish data

Comment: Also, EPSG::2157, IRENET95 / Irish Transverse Mercator is probably more common.